# Vuetify v-app-bar-title component is truncated with plenty of room to spare

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I am using a navigation bar in my Vue/Vuetify app, and added a `v-app-bar-title` component to display the name of the page the user is currently on. However, when I load certain pages, the title text becomes truncated, and only corrects itself if I reload the page. Here is an example of what I mean, I added a red border to the element to show that the text should have enough room: [image: app title truncated]

If I reload the page, the tile returns to normal: [image]

I tried adding the `text-overflow: show` property to the element, but this didn't seem to have any effect. I also added a `min-width` property, but this failed to change the title's behavior.

EDIT: Including a little extra code:

Here's the title component I'm using:

```html
<v-app-bar-title class="title" >{{ title }}</v-app-bar-title>
```

And here's the CSS for it:

```css
.title {
  flex-grow: 10;
  color: var(--text-reverse);
  text-overflow: show;
  // border: 1px solid red;
}
```

I did find a workaround by just replacing the `v-app-bar-title` component with a `span`, but that feels cheap and I'd like to be able to utilize as much of vuetify as possible.

Comment: I am seeing the same behaviour. It is also a simple app bar title. I have included a spacer and an icon as well so I thought it might be caused by this. But also with only the text element residing within the angle brackets the text is cut the first time visiting the website after a reload it is displayed perfectly. I have no clue why and how to fix it. :-(

Comment: @KenJiiii same here it doesnt make sense why its behaving this way

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the solutions mentioned above worked for me. It's always truncated even when there's plenty of space.

Answer (score 5):

try with this

```html
 <v-app-bar-title class="text-no-wrap">{{ title }}</v-app-bar-title>
```

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution that seemed to work in case it is useful:

```
<style>
.v-app-bar-title__content{
  width: 200px !important;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this... It worked for me

```
<v-app-bar-title class="title" >
    <div>{{ title }}</div>
</v-app-bar-title>
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked just fine for me.

Comment: Did not work for me, although it did fix the font weight to what it was before in v-toolbar-title

Answer (score 1):

I had the truncating issue in Safari. Chrome was working fine. I was able to fix by adding `class="grow"`

```
<v-app-bar-title class="grow">
  {{ title }}
</v-app-bar-title>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and didn't want to use `!important`. So I've just replaced `v-app-bar-title` with `v-toolbar-title` and had no this truncation issue any more :)

Answer (score 0):

Great question. Could you share the code of your app-bar component, so we can have a look?

Update:

Is your v-app-bar-title directly in the v-app-bar?

Possible fix, I have never had to change flex-grow on Vuetify components. Have you tried removing the flex-grow?

Additionally you could try in your css title class:

```
  text-overflow: clip;
  overflow: visible;
```

Comment: This is not a great answer to a great question. Therefore please use the comment section.

Comment: Hi Jens, please see the edit I posted with the relevant code!

Answer (score 0):

We can make use of the v-toolbar-title component.
This worked for me!

[Example for toolbar title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwJgR.png)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30313698)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add  space between v-app-bar-titles then adding margin is the best i got here

```
<v-app-bar-title style="color:white" class="title">
        Title here
 </v-app-bar-title>
 <v-app-bar-title style="color:white " class="little ml-4">
 </v-app-bar-title>
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.

Fixed with this

```
<style>
  v-app-bar-title__placeholder {
    text-overflow: clip;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you show the placeholder and hide the content in the `v-app-bar-title`, it seems to work.

```
.v-app-bar-title__placeholder {
  visibility: visible !important;
}
.v-app-bar-title__content {
  visibility: hidden !important;
}
```

Comment: !important is an anti-pattern and should not be used. [Uxengineer](https://uxengineer.com/css-specificity-avoid-important-css/).

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me if you are using Vuetify 3:

```
.v-toolbar-title__placeholder{
  width: 200px !important;
}
```